# Select2 убрать сортировку при мульти выборе

Tags: javascript, select2

Настроил Select2 для мульти выбора. Теперь нужно сохранять очередность выбора, но Select2 выбирает options и сортирует.
Условно есть 3 опции для выбора

```
 <select id="partners" name="partners[]" multiple>
          <option value="1" >first</option>
          <option value="2">second</option>
          <option value="3">third</option>
 </select>
```

И вне зависимости от очередности выбора результат сортируется по индексу

```
"partners" => array:3 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
]
```

В документации не нашел как убрать эту сортировку. Может кто сталкивался?

**UPDATE**
нашел такое решение

```
$("#partners").on("select2:select", function (evt) {

    let element = evt.params.data.element;
    let $element = $(element);

    window.setTimeout(function () {

        if ( $("#partners").find(":selected").length > 1) {
            let $second = $("#partners").find(":selected").eq(-2)
            $element.detach();
            $second.after($element);
        } else {
            $element.detach();
            $("#partners").prepend($element);
        }

        $("#partners").trigger("change");
    }, 1);
});

$("#partners").on("select2:unselect", function (evt) {
    if ($("#partners").find(":selected").length) {
        let element = evt.params.data.element;
        let $element = $(element);
        $("#partners").find(":selected").after($element);
    }
});
```

Но теперь при удалении элемента из селекта он дублируется в выборе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел рабочий вариант. Надеюсь кому-то поможет

```
$("#partners").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    let element = evt.params.data.element
    let $element = $(element)

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if ( $("#partners").find(":selected").length > 1) {
            let $second = $("#partners").find(":selected").eq(-2)
            $element.detach()
            $second.after($element)
        } else {
            $element.detach()
            $("#partners").prepend($element)
        }
        $("#partners").trigger("change")
    }, 1)
})

$("#partners").on("select2:unselect", function (evt) {
    if ($("#partners").find(":selected").length) {
        let element = evt.params.data.element
        let $element = $(element)
        $element.detach()
        $("#partners").find(":selected").eq(-1).after($element)
    }
})
```

Возможно есть лишние действия или код не оптимизирован, но работает для множественного выбора. Не возвращает исходный порядок..